# Is it possible in Woocommerce to have two different checkout forms? (delivery and take away)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

So I've been trying to make this work with no results.

I'm making a restaurant website, and I want the option for take away or delivery. The idea is to have two buttons under the cart and if you press the "take away" one you'll be presented with a form with only name, phone and email fields and no delivery costs, and if you press the "delivery" button well, the standard form with all the fields and delivery costs.

Is that possible?

I tried unsetting the fields* if the page slug is "take-away" but Woocommerce still says they are needed. But this doesn't solve the whole problem, really.

*Or maybe I did something wrong? Here's the code:

```
function filter_form($pageSlug) {
if($pageSlug == 'take-away') {
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_checkout_fields' );
    function custom_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_country']);
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_1']);
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_2']);
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_postcode']);
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_city']);
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_state']);
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_company']);

        return $fields;
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: So, to clarify a few things. I have the typical button that goes to the regular checkout form and another button that takes you to a page where I added the shortcode for the checkout. In that page, with the code I added, I unset the unnecessary fields. The issue is that Woocommerce still asks for them, apparently since version 3 that's a thing and I haven't found a way ACTUALLY remove the need for them. Plus, the "local pickup" instead of delivery should be preselected on that page/form. I'm just not sure if a) there's a way to remove unnecessary fields for good and b) I can have different delivery systems by default for each form.

Comment: Yes it's, but you should give a more complete code than the one provided in your question… How are selected delivery or take away? Are they shipping methods? please update your question to clarify things

Answer (score 0):

Why not use 1 checkout form, and hide the unneeded fileds?

The fields can have values as per default but on take-away they are hidden from the user.

It reduces the need for a second checkout process and keeps things simple

Comment: I haven't found a way to remove unnecessary input fields without Woocommerce still asking for them on checkout. Apparently that's the behaviour now in version 3+...

Comment: Just hide the inputs with jquery: $('#inputid).hide();

Comment: yes, they still have the default values and should pass through

Comment: What defaults? There are no defaults, they're empty as far as I can see.

Comment: oh yes. so you can auto fill them too with jquery. you can always make the billing address the company address...